# Windows IRP function call for opening and saving files

Tags: windows, filesystems, minifilter, irp

I'm currently working on a minifilter driver, and I need to intercept this kind of events :

- Listing files inside a folder
- Opening a file in an application
- Closing this file
- Modify and save the file

From what I read, I guess I need to filter IRP_MJ_CREATE, IRP_MJ_READ, IRP_MJ_WRITE, but I need somethings better than a guess.

How can I know precisely which IRP will be send for each events ?

Comment: Use the minifilter driver to have any hope for surviving this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/i-o-requests-generated-by-the-minifilter-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Listing file inside folder: **IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL** . Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-directory-control) for more information.
2. Opening a file in an application: **IRP_MJ_CREATE** . Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-create) for more information.
3. Closing the file: **IRP_MJ_CLEANUP** and **IRP_MJ_CLOSE**
4. Modifying the file: **IRP_MJ_WRITE**, **IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION** ( specifically the **FileEndOfFileInformation** and **FileValidDataLengthInformation** information classes), **IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL** ( specifically **FSCTL_OFFLOAD_WRITE**, 
   **FSCTL_WRITE_RAW_ENCRYPTED** and **FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA** fsctl codes).

Good luck.